# App crashes after clicking scan button for the first time but the app works after i reopen it

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an indoor location services app in android studio.There is a scan button which start the discovery of BLE devices. When i click on the scan button,the app crashes. But when i reopen the app and click on the scan button again,it works.

i tried this taken from one of the projects from stackoverflow.

Class variable:

```
private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = null;

final BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBtAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();

if (mBtAdapter == null || !mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
}

public void onScanButton(){
    if (mBtAdapter.isEnabled()){
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }
}
```

this is my code

```
    BluetoothManager btManager; //field 'btManager' is never used
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    BluetoothLeScanner btScanner;
    Button startScanningButton;
    Button stopScanningButton;
    TextView peripheralTextView;
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        peripheralTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.peripheralTextView);
        peripheralTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        startScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartScanButton);
        startScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startScanning();
            }
        });

        stopScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopScanButton);
        stopScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopScanning();
            }
        });
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        final BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
        btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

        if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        // Make sure we have access coarse location enabled, if not, prompt the user to enable it
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
            builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect peripherals.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            peripheralTextView.append("MAC address: " + result.getDevice().getAddress() + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() + "TxPower:" + result.getTxPower() + "\n");

            // auto scroll for text view
            final int scrollAmount = peripheralTextView.getLayout().getLineTop(peripheralTextView.getLineCount()) - peripheralTextView.getHeight();
            // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
            if (scrollAmount > 0)
                peripheralTextView.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    System.out.println("coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void startScanning() {
        System.out.println("start scanning");
        peripheralTextView.setText("");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        System.out.println("stopping scanning");
        peripheralTextView.append("Stopped Scanning");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The logcat shows 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)' on a null object reference

at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$6.run(MainActivity.java:137)

at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace to your question? You might also point out from which line of your code the exception is coming from. -- Note as well that you `btAdapter != null` check comes to late, as you already invoked `getBluetoothLeScanner()` on it.

Comment: I just added the complete stacktrace to my question.

Comment: So btScanner seems to be null. How is the code before the `startScanning` method related to it? It does look like you copy & pasted some things into your question, but without providing their proper boundaries. Consider posting an [mre].

Comment: Note that getBluetoothLeScanner() returns null if you have no access to it (`Javadoc: Will return null if Bluetooth is turned off or if Bluetooth LE Advertising is not supported on this device`). So a reason might be that its just not enabled yet. (see impl of BluetoothAdapter#getLeAccess())

Comment: Before i click the Scan button,a prompt will be display asking to turn on the bluetooth.So bluetooth will be turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Before i click the Scan button,a prompt will be display asking to turn
>   on the bluetooth.So bluetooth will be turned on

You are wrong about that part. You ask the user to enable it, but it might not have happened yet. At least you need to get the Scanner later on.

Currently you set the Scanner reference before the permission requesting has been initiated.

This also explains why it works after your App has crashed for the first time, because the 2nd time you come here the Permission has been enabled.

---

From the Javadoc of `BluetoothAdapter#getBluetoothLeScanner()`:

> Will return null if Bluetooth is turned off or if Bluetooth LE
>   Advertising is not supported on this device.

---

You can change your code to:

```
    public void startScanning() {

        btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        if (btScanner == null) {
            // not enabled yet or not supported
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("start scanning");
        peripheralTextView.setText("");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know about that! I thought once the bluetooth on my navigation bar is blue means it is on. Anyway your codes work and thank you very much for time to help me with my problems. However i still have other queries is it alright if i ask you i cant post a new question anymore

Comment: You should post new questions for that.

Comment: i can only post a new question once every 90 mins.